# firebase_core & firebase_messaging not compitable with cocoapods

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Please help me, now I used firebase_core: ^2.20.0 & firebase_messaging: ^14.7.2 with platform :ios, 12.0, if package firebase_core &firebase_messaging remove form pubspec.yaml it work no problem

I was trying

-sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
-arch -x86_64 pod repo update
-arch -x86_64 pod install
but now not working, usually working for me.

result debug:
[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Failed+to+parse+JSON+at+file%3A+%27%2FUsers%2Fmbp-m1%2F.cocoapods%2Frepos%2Ftrunk%2FSpecs%2F0%2Fb%2F5%2FPromisesObjC%2F2.3.1%2FPromisesObjC.podspec.json%27.%0A%0Aunexpected+token+at+%27%27&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

- okay
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1377 [closed] [1 comment]
  26 Dec 2013
- Mix pods with different deployment targets
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1376 [closed] [4 comments]
  16 Apr 2014
- CocoaPods presumes that every private repo has an origin remote
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1378 [closed] [1 comment]
  23 Sep 2013

and 11952 more at:
[https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=Failed%20to%20parse%20JSON%20at%20file%3A%20%27%2FUsers%2Fmbp-m1%2F.cocoapods%2Frepos%2Ftrunk%2FSpecs%2F0%2Fb%2F5%2FPromisesObjC%2F2.3.1%2FPromisesObjC.podspec.json%27.%0A%0Aunexpected%20token%20at%20%27%27&type=Issues&utf8=✓](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=Failed%20to%20parse%20JSON%20at%20file%3A%20%27%2FUsers%2Fmbp-m1%2F.cocoapods%2Frepos%2Ftrunk%2FSpecs%2F0%2Fb%2F5%2FPromisesObjC%2F2.3.1%2FPromisesObjC.podspec.json%27.%0A%0Aunexpected%20token%20at%20%27%27&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)